# How to get file by ObjectId in jgit

Tags: java, jgit

I have some objectId from each files in my directory and some time after I want to find this file by objectId.
I can make it only like hard way... but maybe there is/are some another solution/s ?

This is my way

```
public String findFolderDtoNameByObjectId(Repository repository, String objectId) throws IOException {
    Ref head = repository.findRef(Constants.HEAD);
    if (head == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    try (RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repository)) {
        RevCommit commit = walk.parseCommit(head.getObjectId());
        RevTree tree = commit.getTree();

        try (TreeWalk treeWalk = new TreeWalk(repository)) {
            treeWalk.addTree(tree);
            treeWalk.setRecursive(true);
            while (treeWalk.next()) {
                if (treeWalk.getObjectId(0).getName().equals(objectId)) {
                    GitFileDto dto = new GitFileDto();
                    dto.setFullPath(treeWalk.getPathString());
                    dto.setName(treeWalk.getNameString());
                    dto.setObjectId(treeWalk.getObjectId(0).getName());
                    dto.setContent(getContentFromTree(treeWalk, repository));
                    return dto;         
                 } else if (treeWalk.isSubtree()) {
                    treeWalk.enterSubtree();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Answer is

```
public GitFileDto findFileDtoByObjectId(Repository repository, String objectId) throws IOException {

    Ref head = repository.findRef(HEAD);
    try (RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repository)) {
        RevCommit commit = walk.parseCommit(head.getObjectId());
        RevTree tree = commit.getTree();

        try (TreeWalk treeWalk = new TreeWalk(repository)) {
            treeWalk.addTree(tree);
            treeWalk.setRecursive(true);
            while (treeWalk.next()) {
                ObjectId objectId1 = treeWalk.getObjectId(0);
                if (objectId1 != null && objectId.equals(objectId1.getName())) {
                    return getGitFileDto(repository, treeWalk);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    throw new Exception(String.format("There is no file with objectId: %s ", objectId));
}


private GitFileDto getGitFileDto(Repository repository, TreeWalk treeWalk) throws IOException {

    GitFileDto dto = new GitFileDto();
    dto.setFullPath(treeWalk.getPathString());
    dto.setName(treeWalk.getNameString());
    
    ObjectId objectId = treeWalk.getObjectId(0);

    dto.setObjectId(objectId.getName());

   try (ObjectReader objectReader = repository.newObjectReader()) {
        ObjectLoader objectLoader = objectReader.open(objectId);
        byte[] bytes = objectLoader.getBytes();
       
        dto.setContent(new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
    return dto;
}
```

But I don't like this, because I have to parse the whole tree by myself and I think it is wierd and slow

Answer (score 0):

Not sure 100%, but try this out...

```
ObjectId oid = ObjectId.fromString(objectId);
ObjectDatabase od = repository.getObjectDatabase();
if(od.has​(oid)) {
    // whatever you want to do with the object
    // Load using..  ObjectLoader ol = od.open​(AnyObjectId objectId);
    // Or return Name
}
```

Comment: its only show is iexist file or not. But I need to get it in tree of commits or something like that

Comment: I am not sure about the exact usecase.  From the code above, finally you seem to be returning the getNameString() only.  So, not sure why it has to be loaded from the tree of commits.  If you want the entire tree structure, then you have to do the way you have done.  If you only need to check and get details of an arbitrary ObjectID, then the way I have suggested can be used.

Comment: I updated my return value. So, let's look this situation. From front I get only objectId for any crud operation. So I want to find by objectId my GIT-object and update it. How can I do that. Additionally, I to make need the same operations with folders too.

Comment: Not sure, but try using ```TreeWalk treeWalk = new TreeWalk(repository); treeWalk.reset​(ObjectId.fromString(objectId))```.  Then you can use treeWalk.getPathString() and other treeWalk methods to fill up your DTO.
Check the documentation of the reset method.

Comment: It seems I was looking for... I need some time to verify. Actually I don't understand Treewalk.reset() and RevWalk.dispose(). Wen I have to use it... I thought it's about return to initial state, but your example shows another action

Comment: I did `TreeWalk treeWalk = new TreeWalk(repository); 
treeWalk.reset(ObjectId.fromString("6e8e3a199db2896a6c4958e8592ec08966efbee4"));
System.out.println(treeWalk.getPathString() + " " + treeWalk.getNameString() + " " + treeWalk.getObjectId(0) + " "
            + treeWalk.getAttributes());` But id doesn't work with file. It works only with folders. I need more solutions : ) Your workaround tells `org.eclipse.jgit.errors.IncorrectObjectTypeException: Object 6e8e3a199db2896a6c4958e8592ec08966efbee4 is not a tree.`